# Reviewing a proof to show that a subgroup of a cyclic group is also cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

I want to prove the following statement:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of a cyclic group $G$, here, finite. Then $H$ is also cyclic.

My question is about an attempt that I include below; in particular, about the final paragraph, specifically the highlighted sentence. I know there're other questions on this topic, but I've tried to prove it independently avoiding looking at them. I'm not interested in other proofs (unless they're directly relevant with the approach I've attempted).

---

Proof attempt:

$G$ is a cyclic group $\implies$ $G$ is made up of powers of an element $a$ (the generator):

$$G=\{a^0, a^1, a^2,...,a^{p-1}\}$$

$H$ will also only contain powers of $a$:

$$H=\{a^0, a^{i_1}, a^{i_2},...,a^{i_{m-1}}\}$$

noting that $a^0=e$ must be one of them.

Using Langrange's theorem, we know that the order of $H$ must divide the order of $G$. And then, the set:

$$\{a^{p/m}, \left(a^{p/m}\right)^2,\left(a^{p/m}\right)^3,...,\underbrace{\left(a^{p/m}\right)^m}_{=a^p=e}\}$$

is made of $m$ different elements, because $a^i\neq a^j \ \forall \ i,j \leq p \ \textrm{if} \ i\neq j$ (as the element $a$ generates $G$). That set, is also closed under multiplication, it's associative, has inverses, and an identity element. This is, that set is a group.

Such group will be a cyclic subgroup of $G$, and there'll be (at least) one such subgroup for every divisor of $p$. There won't be subgroups of any other order (Lagrange's theorem). **But also, there can be only one group of each order (up to isomorphism).** Therefore, these cyclic subgroups exhaust the subgroups of $G$, and this proves that all subgroups of $G$ are cyclic.

Comment: "Is the proof [...] satisfactory in all respects[.]" I direct you to the instructions in the `solution-verification` tag description: " "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so." The site is not meant to be a "proof checking" site where you post a proof with dozens of steps, and your question is essentially dozens of "And is this right?"

Comment: You should say that the group is *finite*.  Based on your work.

Comment: You seem to have either assumed the fact that there is a single subgroup of each order, or the fact that every subgroup is of the form $\{a^{p/m}, \dotsc\}$ (depending on exactly what you mean by "such subgroup" and "group of each order" in the last paragraph). Whichever one you assumed, that step requires proof, and in fact the proof of those facts is more or less exactly what you've been asked to prove in the first place!

Comment: Try taking the *smallest* power of $a$ contained in the subgroup.   Then argue that it generates (using the minimality).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin my apologies, I should've read that. I edited the question to highlight the doubtful step. But now, after reading other comments
 I'm struggling to find the reason for doubt, as seems clear that the proof attempt doesn't support that step.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen thanks for pointing that out. I meant to state the first fact that you mention, grounding it on the second fact... Now it's clear to me that, as to what my attempt shows, there could be subgroups of other forms different to the one I show.

Answer (score 1):

I am just a student so take my answer with a grain of salt, but below there is a different prove to your question. I hope this will help you or other student.

The group is $(G;*)$.

1- We writte $g'$ the element of $G$ s.t. $G = \langle g'\rangle $

2- $\forall h \in H \Rightarrow h \in G$ because $ H \subseteq G $.  As $G$ is a  cyclic group by assumption $\forall h \in H, \exists k \in \mathbb{Z} $ s.t $ g'^k=h $.
Now we choose $h'=g'^{k} \in H$ the element of $H$ that can be expressed as the smallest integer power of $g'$.

3-  Any power $\mathbb{Z}$ of $h' = g'^{k}$ is in $H$ as by assumption $H$ is a group. Thus $\langle h'\rangle \subseteq H $.

4- It let us to prove that $H \subseteq \langle h'\rangle$.

- $\forall h \in H \Rightarrow h \in G \Rightarrow \exists  l \in \mathbb{Z} $ s.t. $h=g^l$. And we can write $ l = kq + r$ and $ q,r \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \leq r < k $ and $k$ as define in "3-".
- So $g^l = g^{kq}*g^r = (g^k)^q * g^r \Rightarrow (g^k)^{-q} * g^l = g^r  $. Remember that $ g^k \in H \Rightarrow (g^k)^{-q} \in H $ too as $(g^k)^{-1} \in H $  by property of $H$ a sub group and because $(g^k)^{-q} = (g^k)^{-1} * ... * (g^k)^{-1} $ "q" times we can conclude $(g^k)^{-q}, g^l \in H$.
- But if $(g^k)^{-q}, g^l \in H \Rightarrow g^{-qk+l}=g^r \in H$ too.
- Beware that $0 \leq r  < k$ and that here on one side $-qk+l \leq 0$ and on the other side $-qk+l = r \geq 0$. Hence the only solution is $r=0$ .
  In conclusion $g^l$ can be generated by $h'=g^k$. And this prove that $H \subseteq \langle h'\rangle$

Q.E.D.

Comment: I doubt you mean "precocious": indicative of early development. How can we be precocious with your answer? Did you mean something else?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for your comment. Indeed you were right I ve edited my answer.

Comment: Were you thinking of a word like "precautious maybe", intending something like "be careful because it might be wrong"? I think "cautious" would be more idiomatic, or you could say "take my answer with a grain of salt". By the way, your argument looks fine to me! I think it doesn't really answer the question, though.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen thank I ve edited my answer according to your suggestion